# Sketch of proof of Uniformization Theorem

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Can somebody give me the sketch of the proof of the uniformization theorem, given that every compact Riemann surface admits a non-constant meromorphic function. (I am not so sure these two are indeed related or not.)

I just want to know how the story goes on.

Comment: Here's a similar question on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10516/uniformization-theorem-for-riemann-surfaces

Comment: Actually I already read the answers on the link, but I want some more details, the overall outline of the proof.